# Sitecore 6.6 Item Buckets Module: Inactive Bucket Button

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, bucket

I have Sitecore 6.6 with SIP 3.2 running and want to use Item Buckets (updating to Sitecore 7 doesn't work for us in this case). So I installed ([the Module](https://github.com/jerrong/Sitecore-Item-Buckets)) and got the new menus icons to show in Sitecore. The problem is that when I select an item in the content tree, the Bucket button (to convert an item into a bucket) is always inactive. See the following screenshot:

[image: Bucket Button inactive]

Google search didn't help. Any idea what is wrong?

EDIT:

Access Viewer:
[image: Access Viewer]

Security Editor:
[image: Security Editor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the item you want to turn into a bucket MUST be locked (click on Home -> Edit). Then the Bucket button is active. Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 scenarios when this button will be disabled:

1. This item already is a bucket
2. Item is **NOT** locked
3. User doesn't have access rights to `bucket:makebucket` on the chosen item.

From what you wrote and from your screenshot I think it's the 2nd or 3rd scenario in your case. Check whether the item is locked and try to use **Access viewer** and **Security Editor** to check/assign proper access rights.

---

**EDIT:**

You can always debug this command and see what is the reason why it's disabled.

Create a class in your project called `MakeBucket` (change `My.Assembly.Namespace` to your project namespace):

```cs
namespace My.Assembly.Namespace
{
    using System.Collections.Specialized;
    using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
    using Sitecore.ItemBucket.Kernel.ItemExtensions.Axes;
    using Sitecore.ItemBucket.Kernel.Kernel.Pipelines;
    using Sitecore.ItemBucket.Kernel.Security;
    using Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands;

    internal class MakeBucket : Command
    {
        public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(context, "context");
            var items = context.Items;
            Assert.IsNotNull(items, "Context items list is null");
            Context.ClientPage.Start("uiBucketItems", new BucketArgs(items[0], new NameValueCollection()));
        }

        public override CommandState QueryState(CommandContext context)
        {
            Error.AssertObject(context, "context");

            var item = context.Items[0];
            if (!new BucketSecurityManager(item).IsAllowedToCreateBucket)
            {
                return CommandState.Disabled;
            }

            if (!item.Locking.HasLock())
            {
                return CommandState.Disabled;
            }

            return item.IsBucketItemCheck() ? CommandState.Disabled : CommandState.Enabled;
        }
   }
}
```

and register it in `App_Config/Include/Sitecore.ItemBuckets.config` instead of original `item:bucket` command:

```xml
<command name="item:bucket" type="My.Assembly.Namespace.MakeBucket,My.Assembly" />
```

Attach with debugger and put a breakpoint in `QueryState` method.

Comment: Good point. I now assigned the rights for make und unmake bucket in the access viewer, but the Bucket button is still inactive.

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot from access viewer showing your access rights for this item? Can you check if this item is locked?

Comment: Added screenshots of Access Viewer and Security Editor to first post. The item I want to turn into a bucket is "Aktuelles". This item shouldn't be locked. There is no lock symbol in the content editor in front of it.